# Bootloader frozen on Nexus 10

Tags: boot-loop, fastboot, bootloader

My Nexus 10s bootloader is stuck, it keeps saying "Downloading... Do not turn off target!!" and fastboot commands have no affect on it. I also can't use the volume rocker to boot into recovery or reboot the bootloader. If I try to boot it shows the Google logo and then the android boot-animation, which continues on indefinetly.

When this happend I was trying to flash the new system image onto it. I had already unlocked the bootloader without problems, but it may have been accidentaly disconected while running the flash-all script.

Can I restet my bootloader or flash android in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold Power until it shutsdown, then you need to hold Power and Volume - and + until you see the fastboot screen